# Problem with iframe cloaking, How can I add all my website files into a domain name itself?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, html, javascript, looking-for-hosting

I have come to the point where a “simple” way of building websites is just not able to facilitate larger projects. I have been using repl.it to simply host and read files I have coded in HTML, CSS, JS and other environments. I simply just cloak over a domain (which uses an iframe) that is a very cheap solution for a low quality performance website. The code itself is fine, I am currently on a chat website application and the iframe simply doesn’t handle to the simple features that other devices may have. For example, the iframe looks fine on a computer or larger screen device, but once I use a phone to test the site, the iframe tries to cloak over it as it’s a desktop screen. From the repl.it itself, it is a responsive design, the website fits all screen resolution borders and looks good on every device, this only works from the repl.it hosting domain which is just too long and ugly and that is the only reason why I am using a cloak to hide the name, but with that comes other problems.

Is there a way I can directly put my files over a domain name itself, or host? The website uses socket.io as the server and it all works out, it’s just when cloaked, the screen borders are zoomed right out so it can try and fit a computer screen.

The zoomed out one is when it is cloaked, and the perfect one is how I would like it to look as it is directly hosted off replit

[image]

[image]